# ViewPager2 don't recreate ui after swipped

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

I am using viewpager2 and in adapter class after I click the button I want to change the button color. But after 7-8 swipe without clicking the button, buttons color gets changed so viewpager doesn't recreate the ui. Here is my adapter class:

```
class MyAdapter(private val mData :List<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
inner  class MyViewHolder(private val binding:ItemDataBinding) :RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(data :String) {
        binding.mText.text = data
        binding.btnclick.setOnClickListener {
            binding.btnclick.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.blue))
        }
    }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    (holder as MyViewHolder).bind(mData[position])
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val binding = ItemDataBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
    return MyViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mData.size
}
```

}

And in main activity here is how I declare View pager

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val data = listOf<String>("s","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","ı","i")
    val  viewpager = findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.mViewPager)
    val adapter = MyAdapter(data)
    viewpager.adapter = adapter

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)` to `0` and refer [this](https://www.codetd.com/en/article/6438846) and [that](https://developpaper.com/viewpager-2-major-updates-to-support-offscreen-page-limit/_) for more info on `setOffscreenPageLimit` and caching

```
viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit( 0 )
```